# Saving raster from QGIS for use in CAD

Tags: raster, export, pyqgis-3, cad

I am trying to save my raster layer as follows:

```py
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('file_to_write.tif')
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
rlayer = lu.getLayerByName('raster_name')
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()

if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
    return
file_writer.writeRaster(
    pipe,
    provider.xSize(),
    provider.ySize(),
    provider.extent(),
    provider.crs())
```

The problem is that the output is a totally black image where I can barely see the content.
The script used to load the raster can be found below:

```py
def load_raster(path, iface, opt=0):
   fileInfo = QFileInfo(path)
   baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
   layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
   crs = layer.crs()
   crs.createFromId(2100)
   layer.setCrs(crs)
   raster_trans = layer.renderer().rasterTransparency()
   ltr = QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentSingleValuePixel()
   tr_list = []
   ltr.min = 150  # Or another value
   ltr.max = 255  # Or another value
   ltr.percentTransparent = 100  # Or another value
   tr_list.append(ltr)
   raster_trans.setTransparentSingleValuePixelList(tr_list)
   provider = layer.dataProvider()
   provider.setNoDataValue(1, 0)
   QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

For some rasters, the above work like a charm but most of the times the output is total black. What could it be wrong?

Comment: So called totally black images are very often images which have a large bit depth (16, 32, 64 bit) but data values are all close to the low end of the full scale. Could this be your case as well?

Comment: @user30184 I think so because when I load the saved file in cad I can barely see the content.